# How (and where) should a hook be defined to autoupload a website to production?

Tags: git, githooks

I have a central server acting as a git server, and I push my changes from another pc. I work in parallel with another developer, too. He prepared a hook in the git server so when we pushed it pulls any change.

What we would want to do now is to also pull from a production server. We work with two main branches (master and stable), so when we decide to commit something as stable, we would like the production server to pull it in any way. I'm not plenty sure if it is possible to pull on demand, but I have found little to no information about this aspect. Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not exactly clear and requires more details on your setup.

If you want to  pull in your production server ( or push to your production server from the central server ), and if you are using a hook like `update` , `post-receive` or `post-update`, you can easily make them `pull` or `push` only if you commit to the stable branch.

Taking the specific example of an `update` hook on the central server, it takes three parameters:

```
- the name of the ref being updated,
- the old object name stored in the ref,
- and the new objectname to be stored in the ref.
```

By checking the name of the ref to be what you want( stable ) and then doing a `push` or `pull` to the production server will help you achieve the selective update that you want.

http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Answer (score 0):

You can't push to the production server because a) by default git won't push to a non-bare repository, and b) if you force it, it can only update the repo, not the working directory. You have to get into the production repository directory and pull from there. You could automate that with a post-receive hook on the central repo, and you should be prepared to deal with file ownership issues.

Comment: What about pushing to the production server and moving the new files to the desired folder using a post-recieve?

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll give it a try in a couple of days, once I use the system again. I'll keep you informed =)

Comment: Your post-receive is probably going to need to cd into the working directory and then `git checkout master`. Ought to work.

Comment: Bear in mind, that won't get you around file ownership issues. Entirely possible that the user running to handle the receive may not have rights on the files in the directory. In which case you'll probably need to use sudo, which will probably need to be configured to have your git user as a sudoer and to run without at tty.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think about that. Anyway, I've spoken to my teammate and we came up to another possible solution: from our lan git server, when it recieves a "stable" branch push, connect through sftp to the prod server and upload the new files there (or maybe a fresh update). We reduce the number of hooks, plus I think we could handle permissions in a better way.

Comment: You could also trigger the production repo's pull from your dev box. So, you push your code into the central repo, then ssh to the dev machine, cd to the document root, and git pull. You could even set it up as a post-commit hook (maybe looking to see if the committed branch is called "dev" or something).